# Grep for string in first line of all files in directory and descendants

Tags: shell, grep

How can I grep for a given string in all files in the current directory, and recursively so, only considering the first line? (the #! line, if present, but only if #! is in the -first- line)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not forced to use grep:

```
find . -type f -exec \
  awk 'FNR==1 && /GIVEN_STRING/ { print FILENAME ": " $0; }; FNR>1 {nextfile}' {} +
```

This causes a lot less CPU load as one process (or very few) does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
find . -type f -exec head -1 {} \; | grep "GIVEN_STRING"
```

Comment: Two processes for every checked file?

Comment: one process for every checked file, 2 processes to get everything set up. besides, spawning a `head` for each file isn't that big a deal. not with today's computers and kernels, anyway.